# selection range in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've searched for days but couldn't find one solid solution to get the selection start / end in Internet explorer, I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235411/is-there-an-internet-explorer-approved-substitute-for-selectionstart-and-selectio) and [this](http://the-stickman.com/web-development/javascript/finding-selection-cursor-position-in-a-textarea-in-internet-explorer/) solution.

Both of them involve using *document.selection.createRange()*, the below code will work quite good but if you go to a new line (press enter one or more time) and then try to get the selection start/end you will end up before you pressed enter. From what I see createRange() won't select the latest empty line breaks, I don't want the code to get too messy so is there a different solution for this?

```
function selecetion_range()
{
 var range = document.selection.createRange();
    var stored_range = range.duplicate();
    stored_range.moveToElementText(textarea[0]);
    stored_range.setEndPoint('EndToEnd', range );

    return {
          start: stored_range.text.replace(/\r/g,'').length - range.text.replace(/\r/g,'').length,
          end: stored_range.text.replace(/\r/g,'').length
 }
}
```

**edit:**

To clarify the problem, lets say my cursor is at the end of this quote:

> "some random text
>
> <here>"

once I use the above code the selection start would be:

> "some random text<here>"

Comment: @Dennis: you should post an answer with the link to your solution and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution [here](http://linebyline.blogspot.com/2006/11/textarea-cursor-position-in-internet.html), its a huge code block so I don't want to post the answer here.