# Bind "Ctrl+Alt+L" to insert some predefined string into focused textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to insert predefined string into  **focused** textarea to cursor position? For example, I'm typing some text in textarea, then I'm pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and `<a href="" title=""></a>` is inserted into current cursor position.

Comment: I've found answer to my question at this code http://github.com/tzuryby/jquery.hotkeys/blob/master/jquery.hotkeys.js

Comment: Glad you found an answer, though I must warn that you should be careful which key combinations are used.  For example, Ctrl-Alt-L while using the GNOME desktop on Linux locks the screen, similar to Win-L on Windows.  Another example is Ctrl-R (like stackoverflow), which refreshes the page in Web browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use the `keydown` event and one of the caret-position-in-textarea functions floating around on Stack Overflow. For the key detection, note I've had to use the `keydown` event rather than the `keypress` event (which is what should be used for detecting what character has been typed) because IE doesn't fire the `keypress` events for Ctrl+Alt+L, so this could go wrong on differently mapped keyboards. For the cursor position, I've copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea/263796#263796) and have used something similar myself. See these answers for discussion of the problems with this in IE:

[Caret position in textarea, in characters from the start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea)
[Is there an Internet Explorer approved substitute for selectionStart and selectionEnd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235411/is-there-an-internet-explorer-approved-substitute-for-selectionstart-and-selectio/235582#235582)

Also, note that you may want to position the cursor somewhere sensible after doing this, which my code doesn't cover.

```
function getCaret(el) {
    if ("selectionStart" in el) {
        return el.selectionStart;
    } else if (document.selection) {
        el.focus();

        var r = document.selection.createRange();
        if (r == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        var re = el.createTextRange(), rc = re.duplicate();
        re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark());
        rc.setEndPoint("EndToStart", re);

        return rc.text.length;
    }
    return 0;
}

var textArea = document.getElementById("yourTextarea");
textArea.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.ctrlKey && evt.altKey && evt.keyCode == 76) {
        var cursorPos = getCaret(this);
        this.value = this.value.slice(0, cursorPos)
                   + '<a href="" title=""></a>'
                   + this.value.slice(cursorPos)
        return false; // Prevent any default browser behaviour
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Ctrl-Alt-L, but there are definately ways to do this.  For example:

```
<textarea name="MyText" id="MyText" onKeyPress="handleKey(this);" 
onKeyDown="CaptureKeyDown(this);"></textarea>

<script>
    function handleKey(ta) {
        if (event.keyCode == 12) { // Ctrl-L
            // Do your insert here
        }
    }
</script>
```

It is more complicated than this.  Check out this HTML editor (written in HTML and JavaScript) at http://www.boltbait.com/htmleditor/ (the source can be downloaded there).

EDIT: Oops! I didn't see your jquery tag.

Comment: It's not a problem, it's ok without jQuery.