# jQuery change keypress to text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, special-characters, keypress

I am looking for a cross-browser (can be based on jquery) way to change the keypress done by a user.

Capturing it is no problem. Changing behaviour in a cross-browser compatible manner, seems to be a problem.

Essentially I need to map some extra keys to special characters. Like ctrl+alt+p should enter a special character in a text field or textarea.

Thanks,

-dennis

Comment: Be careful with this. Depending on the browser (and OS) you could be covering up shortcuts, that the user is expecting to work, or you won't be able to to catch them at all. Ctrl-Alt-... shortcuts, for example, are often used for system-wide functions in Linux.

Comment: I now. But this is a tradeoff with functionality. This is a situation where the users need to input characters that are typically not on their keyboards/keymappings. The alternative would be to use a mouse to point to a character grid next to each input field.

Comment: Hmm. It seems that this might solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064089/inserting-a-text-where-cursor-is-using-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've covered a cross-browser technique for doing this before on SO: [Can I conditionally change the character entered into an input on keypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923089/can-i-conditionally-change-the-character-entered-into-an-input-on-keypress/3923320#3923320)

You can adapt this for your own mappings. Also, you should use the `keydown` rather than `keypress` event if you're detecting keystrokes involving <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>, since not all browser will fire keypress events when no character is typed.

Answer (score 2):

You can capture a key press, look at the event to see if CTRL or ALT has been pressed. I assume this is pretty much what you are doing?

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("#target").keydown(function(event) 
    {
        if (event.ctrlKey && event.altKey && event.keyCode == '80') {
            alert("Ctrl-Alt-P combination");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to replace the alert() invocation with something that actually writes a character - just possibly another one than the browser would normally write.

Answer (score 0):

[Inserting a text where cursor is using Javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064089/inserting-a-text-where-cursor-is-using-javascript-jquery)

http://skfox.com/jqExamples/insertAtCaret.html