# How to implement this keyboard hooking function in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to implement a keyboard for my language. For example, I want that if you type `"a"` then in the textbox or input box will show: [ka http://cl.cooltext.com/rendered/cooltext530153213.png](http://cl.cooltext.com/rendered/cooltext530153213.png).....If i press "m" it will show: [image]

Now, this is not possible in current webbrowsers because there is no hooking functionality here. For this,I have decided that this algorithm:

1. Detect keycode of the typed letter (in this case `"a"`)
2. Maintain a keymap and found from the keycode (in step1) which key will be replaced by `"a"`
3. Replace the textarea/textInput as: "string before --a--"+ replaced key from step2 + "rest of the portion after --a--"
4. return false so that "a" is not written into the textarea/textInput by the browser.

---

I am searching for a better idea than running **substring** method after keystroke...Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've provided code to do just this on Stack Overflow before: [show different keyboard character from the typed one in google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579219/show-different-keyboard-character-from-the-typed-one-in-google-chrome/3580352#3580352) and [Can I conditionally change the character entered into an input on keypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923089/can-i-conditionally-change-the-character-entered-into-an-input-on-keypress/3923320#3923320), for example.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is exactly the correct way to implement this.