# Is it possible to change symbol before it's printed with javascript?

Tags: javascript

Does anybody know how to change an entered symbol seamlessly with javascript?  Because when I just replace an already-printed symbol with the desired one (something like *onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/,/g,'.')"*), the user sees the replacement occur: you press comma, comma is printed, then it's replaced by a dot.  Of course, it happens quickly so it's not a big problem, but anyway I want the dot to be printed immediately without printing and replacing the comma first.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to cancel default event and add the other character to the input manually

Look at this question it should help you: [how to insert dot instead of comma in js keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633981/how-to-insert-dot-instead-of-comma-in-js-keypress/7634152#7634152)

Answer (score 0):

Try using onkeydown instead and stop the event from propagating.

A quick fiddle I did to try this out ... this is quick and dirty and may cause issues.

http://jsfiddle.net/djgraff209/KpR52/3/

Comment: Use the technique referenced by Jan Pfeifer. It is much more robust than the q&d I did above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , You have to use javascript event like 
1) onkeydown
2) onkeyup 
to achieve your task.
So first try yourself .
If you have further problem  then you can ask..**But First TRY yourself.**