# Text range selection empty desn't work in IE 7,8

Tags: javascript, selection, range

It's little hard to explain problem, so better to show example.

[Test page](http://www.biznet.am/Keyboard/test.php)

Code automatically replaced Latin alphabet to Armenian. In FF/Chrome/Opera it works great.
In IE almost too. **BUT if you select some text an try to write**, typed character is replacing previous.

I tried

```
document.selection.empty();
```

but it doesn't help.

Do you know any method to reset/empty selection and leave cursor in same place in IE?

Thanks!

Comment: The link is to localhost, which -in my case- doesn't contain a `Keyboard/test.php` file ;)

Comment: Maybe you could replace the old char, for example `a`, to `å<span id="cursor"></span>`, then set the selection to span#cursor?

Comment: That span tag is visible in textarea. Maybe it will work for wysiwygs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've written a couple of answers on Stack Overflow that address this:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3580352/96100
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3923320/96100

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your IE-specific code indeed needs some extra code to set the cursor at the correct spot. Have a look at the [MSDN documentation on TextRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), from what I can see you'd need the [collapse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536371%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method?

Also have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area), I think that discusses exactly your problem.