# input field custom controller to transform text

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, internet-explorer-11

This question is related to [show different keyboard character from the typed one in google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579219/show-different-keyboard-character-from-the-typed-one-in-google-chrome/3580352#3580352)

@Tim Down you solution works. However, there is an issue in IE. Latest version of IE, ie IE 11, has a new feature that shows an x as user types into the input field. When entered text is manually transformed, and the default event is cancelled, it allows user to type beyond the x and the text doesn't get shifted to left. If the default event is not cancelled, the text entered gets shifted to the left and cursor stays at the end of the input field besides the x.

Do you have any suggestions/ideas to fix this ?

Cancelling the event and firing an event would fix it, but as already mentioned it doesn't work in chrome.