# Where to find JavaScript documentation?

Tags: javascript, selection-api

I think theres one https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference but for for things like what properties/functions a Textarea object will have, where can I get it?

I know textarea have properties like selectionStart, selectionEnd but what others? where can I find that info?

Comment: Actually in IE up to and including version 8, textareas do not have `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties and you need a fairly complicated workaround to get the equivalent functionality.

Comment: @Tim Down, ... IE again ... I don't like hacks, it just makes code crappy ... but a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974768%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), there is `selectionStart` except that it have a big logo IE9. How can I see what is the alternative for <=IE8?

Comment: I'm afraid that's just how web development is. If you need the IE <= 8 selectionStart/End code, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235411/is-there-an-internet-explorer-approved-substitute-for-selectionstart-and-selectio/4207763#4207763

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Gecko DOM Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference) is pretty complete.

For the dark side (IE-specific stuff), there's also Microsoft's [HTML and DHTML Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533050%28VS.85%29.aspx)

And for cross-browser advice, consult [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/) (thanks Raynos)

Comment: Please dont recomend microsoft's website. People might start using .htc files to do black magic again.

Comment: Of course I don't recommend it, I thought *And for the Dark Side* was pretty obvious. But AFAIK the DOM implementations in IE are somewhat different, so I guess if you are serious about cross browser support, you will have to go there to. It's a necessity, not a recommendation.

Comment: Good point. On that note I would mention http://www.quirksmode.org/ for aiding with serious cross browser support.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to know anything about javascript

Search for it in google and add the word "mdc" on the end. I personally find the internal MDC search bar annoying and unhelpful.

in your case :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLTextAreaElement

[Edit]

I actaully do this for everything. For example rather then wading through the MSDN website if I need to know anything about a transact sql command. I search for the command in google and add "t sql msdn". If only people used the google search engine internally on their websites rather then their own half baked search engine.

Comment: +1 - I do this all the time when I want to double-check something.  For IE specific methods, I add "dhtml msdn" on the end instead.

Comment: @AndyE For IE specific methods I throw the code away and do it properly.

Comment: good luck with that :-p there is no "[doing] it properly" in IE.

Comment: I can top that: for IE specific methods I track down the user's home address and have a special squad break into his house and install a proper browser

Comment: @S.P.Floyd psh! I use IE's ActiveX controls to install ubuntu and reboot their computers. far less hassle and they get a proper OS aswell.