# Finding a word and replacing using regular expressions in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I need information about finding a word and replacing it with regular expressions in javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\b` to specify a word boundary. Just put them around the word that you want to replace.

Example:

```
var s = "That's a car.";
s = /\ba\b/g.replace(s, "the");
```

The variable `s` now contains the string `"That's the car"`. Notice that the "a" in "That's" and "car" are unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't really asked a question, the best I can do is point you here:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

And tell you also that the replace method for a string is `replace`, as in:

```
var myStr = "there is a word in here";
var changedStr = myStr.replace(/word/g, "replacement");
```

Comment: @Renesis: please, w3schools.com is awful, post a better link. How about this one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd thanks for the other link. Not sure I agree that it's awful, even if it's usually light on explanation, it is a succinct reference for syntax.

Comment: @Renesis you can find some discussion about w3schools in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312945/where-to-find-javascript-documentation

Comment: @Sean - I don't see any discussion there - and again, when googling I don't often come up with any top 10 results that are as succinct as w3schools.