# Can you select text inside an input in IE 10+?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, browser, cross-browser

I've seen a lot of different posts in regards to selecting text but haven't seen anything that actually answers the question directly. Are you able to select text inside of an input element and access that text in IE?

For example, I have the following:
    Text inside my input looks like this:

```
Joe Tom Jim Andrew
```

I want to select any one, or all, of those strings and among other things, I am removing what is selected/highlighted from the input.

```
var input = document.getElementById("inputElement");
var start = input.selectionStart;
var end = input.selectionEnd;
text = input.value.substring(start, end);
```

This works great, I'm able to select the text and do with what I need to. Note: I was using window.getSelection() - worked great in Chrome but doesn't work in Firefox. The above solution works fine for both so I'm just using that.

But is it possible to do this in IE? I'm concerned mostly with 10+. Or is it not possible to select text inside an input in IE?

Thanks for the time

The post listed below helped me realize that selection works differently in a text input and helped me with getting it to work in Firefox, but selectionStart and selectionEnd don't work for me in IE. I need an IE solution:

How do I get window.getselection to work for an input type=text field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get window.getselection to work for an input type=text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072155/how-do-i-get-window-getselection-to-work-for-an-input-type-text-field)

Comment: That post doesn't work in IE. It solved the Firefox issue but its not working in IE

Comment: *In most browsers, window.getSelection() only works with selections within text nodes and elements within the document. It doesn't apply to text within <input> and <textarea> elements (although in WebKit window.getSelection().toString() will return the selected text within a focussed text input or textarea.*