# How to select text using Google rangy?

Tags: javascript, selection, rangy

How can I select text and get that selected text using `Rangy`? For example, if I want to build a text editor like the one on Stack Overflow, where if I select a piece of text and click the **B** button, that text is replaced by two asterisks preceding and following the text.

I know that the underlying Javascript must capture the selected text's offset, prepend and append that text by asterisks, and output the new text replacing the previous selected text. How do I accomplish this? The native DOM 3 `setSelection` methods provide some functionality, but these are not highly cross-browser-compatible, whereas `Rangy` is cross-browser. Unfortunately Rangy's documentation is quite poor.

Comment: Ok ok, I did some relentless Googling and found out that I don't need to use rangy. The main problem is being created by IE 6-8, which doesn't support setSelection functions and rely on createTextRange. One of its methods is moveEnd. How to use it? The article at http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/ncz/index.html says that to get the first 3 characters of a textbox, I must have oRange.moveEnd("character", 3 - oTextbox.value.length);. Please explain this.

Comment: I would suggest editing your question (and it's title) to include the additional information. That way users won't need to read the comments to see your actual question.

Comment: This is not strictly relevant to your question, but if you have specific issues with Rangy's documentation then I'd be really pleased to hear them.

Comment: Your question is confusing: are you talking about using a `<textarea>` or a `contenteditable` element? The two have very different selection APIs.

Comment: I am talking about a normal textarea element.

Comment: The documentation hardly provides a constructive example, all of them are vague, not one of them teaches like "So here is a div. It contains the text 'A quick brown fox jumps', and if you do this, this will happen"...All it contains is a list of all its functions and what they do. So I have decided not to use it. Please somebody explain the use of moveend!

Comment: Ok, another update, I now have a fair idea about moveEnd. However does IE 6-8 have a method to get the offset of the selected text? For example, if I select a word in the textarea, press the "b" button, I want to left-pad and right-pad that word with <b> tags, and set the new selection on the entire chunk, that is the opening <b> tag, the originally selected word and the closing <b> tag. IE provides a method to get the selected text, but not its offset, so I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: Rangy itself is for selections and ranges within the regular text on the page, not for textareas. I've written a [separate jQuery plug-in](http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/) for textareas and text inputs.

Comment: Yeah, it is working even in IE, i.e we can access the selectionsStart in IE also, whereas previously we could only modify it, but not get the offset. How did you do it? IE doesn't support it after all. And secondly, it is inconsistent, when you select the first line in the demo textbox and click to get the selection, Firefox shows (0,14) while IE shows (0,16).

Comment: I used [this function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4207763/96100). The reason the offsets are inconsistent is that IE (and Opera) represent line breaks in the `value` property of textareas as `\r\n` while other browsers use `\n`, and `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties are relative to the textarea's `value`.