# Get non selected text from a textbox in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I'm trying to get the non selected text in an Input Text element using IE8, I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/235419/1301872) and was really helpfully, but in the case of the text wasn't selected the function returns the index of start and end of the string.

How can I get the non selected text of the input text element or how can I know when there isn't text selected?

Using jQuery would be helpfully too.

Comment: Which one you want? Just to know if there is text selected?

Comment: When there is non selected text in the input text element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, you'll need something like this:

```
function getNonSelectedText(){
    var elem=document.getElementById('input');
    var selection=document.selection;
    var range=selection.createRange();
    if(range.boundingWidth<1){
        return elem.value;
    }
    var rangePre=range.duplicate();
    rangePre.moveToElementText(range.parentElement());// For <textarea>
    // rangePre.expand('textedit'); // For <input type=text>
    var rangePost=rangePre.duplicate();
    rangePre.setEndPoint('EndToStart',range);
    rangePost.setEndPoint('StartToEnd',range);
    return rangePre.text+rangePost.text;
}
```