# How to add a prototype for a input element?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, prototype

I have a input element:

```
<input type="text" id="t" value="abcdefghij" />
```

I want to create a `selectionStart`

```
document.getElementById("t").selectionStart
```

The functions I need are:

```
function GetSelectionStart(o) {
    if (o.createTextRange) {
        var r = document.selection.createRange().duplicate()
        r.moveEnd('character', o.value.length)
        if (r.text == '') return o.value.length
        return o.value.lastIndexOf(r.text)
    } else return o.selectionStart;
}

function GetSelectionEnd(o) {
    if (o.createTextRange) {
        var r = document.selection.createRange().duplicate()
        r.moveStart('character', -o.value.length)
        return r.text.length
    } else return o.selectionEnd;
}
```

How can I add this "property" to `<input type="text" />` on IE? Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it's a bad idea both in principle and in practice to try extend host objects. Host objects such as DOM elements can do pretty much what they like; in particular, they are not obliged to support what you're trying to do and in IE <= 8, which is what you're targetting with this code, DOM elements simply don't support this. Your options are either to use a function to which you pass an input element, or create a wrapper object for each input that has the methods and properties you need.

Second, your `GetSelectionStart()` and `GetSelectionEnd()` functions are flawed: they will not handle new lines correctly in textareas and have faulty logic around `lastIndexOf` (what if the selected text appears more than once in the input?). I've done quite a lot of work on this, and have come up with what I'm fairly convinced is the best function around for getting input and textarea selections in all major browsers, which I last posted here a couple of days ago: [Is it possible to programmatically detect the caret position within a <input type=text> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185821/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-detect-the-cursor-position-within-a-input-typ/4186100#4186100)

Comment: I was just trying to fix the damn IE. Those functions I just copied from some article http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=IE+selectionstart. Thanks for pointing these flaws and for providing a reliable function. I guess I have no choice, I will have to use a method instead...

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to extend the [`HTMLInputElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6043025) interface, like this:

```
HTMLInputElement.prototype.selectionStart = …
```

However, JavaScript experts consider this a [**bad practice**](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

Answer (score 0):

This is also answered in these questions:

[Caret position in textarea, in characters from the start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea)

[Character offset in an Internet Explorer TextRange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164147/character-offset-in-an-internet-explorer-textrange)

Comment: They are related, but they are not the same question.